# Using UNITY IK with a sphere, and movable plane, how could I keep the sphere "connected" to the plane but respect gravity relitive to the sphere?

Tags: unity, inverse-kinematics

Using the Unity provided IK system with a sphere and a plane in 3d space. How could I keep the sphere "connected" to the plane but respect gravity relative to the sphere?

For example, if the plain and sphere are orientated like

[image: "O_"]

The sphere is "connected" to the ground with IK, and still under the influence of the built-in gravity.

[image]

Additionally, if the plane was rotated vertically (or any other position)

[image]

Comment: IK wouldn't normally be used for positioning a single sphere. We'd use IK where there's a kinematic chain (say a limb with multiple bones/joints), and we want to find an angle for each joint in the chain that puts the end bone in a particular place/orientation. Can you explain how IK relates to this problem? What are the joints we're controlling?

Comment: Hi, thanks! It's essentially a thought experiment to gain an understanding of trying things albeit the "wrong way." (I am assuming) There would only be one "joint" regarding abstraction about the model I would like to use. E.g., the spear, about the plane it is on. IK relates to this problem (I assume) so that the sphere and the plane have a "connected" relationship in 3d space, but the sphere is still under the influence (secondary) to the gravity in world space.

Comment: It sounds like you want a physics constraint, not inverse kinematics at all. No joint chain = no IK.

Comment: I want to maintain that I would like to try this with IK.